# How to arrange the Components in multiple rows in a Scrollpane

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, jscrollpane

I need to add about 600 Images to a Scrollpane, but all the Images are arranged side-by-side

[image: Screenshot]

```
public CollectionPanel(Controller controller)
  this.setBackground(Color.white);
  this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  JPanel content = new JPanel();
  content.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
  JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
  for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i){
    content.add(new Sticker(i+1)); 
  }
  scrollPane.setViewportView(content);
  this.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

How is it possible to arrange them to make a "linebreak" when they reached the end of the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at Rob Camick's [**WrapLayout**](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/).

You can resize the frame, and all your components will be reformatted for you. Here's an example usage

[image][image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestWrapLayout {
    public TestWrapLayout () {
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/stackoverflow2.png"));
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new WrapLayout());
        for (int i = 1; i <= 250; i++) {
            JLabel iconlabel = new JLabel(icon);
            iconlabel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JLabel textlabel = new JLabel(String.valueOf(i));
            textlabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            textlabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            textlabel.setFont(new Font("impact", Font.PLAIN,20));
            iconlabel.add(textlabel);
            panel.add(iconlabel);
        }
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(panel));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                new TestWrapLayout();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, just found it in an old StackOverflow thread and it works properly. The only downside about it is, that with 600 images you see how it rearranges line after line. (maybe because it needs to validate  the layout over and over again to get the current window width).

Answer (score 1):

Use [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html) instead of `FlowLayout` that fits the components side by side.

```
 JPanel content = new JPanel();
 content.setLayout(new GridLayout(rows,1)); 
 //pass no of rows with just one column
```

You can try with [`BoxLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html) as well.

```
JPanel content = new JPanel();
content.setLayout(new BoxLayout(content, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
```

---

Please have a look at [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) & [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more info with working sample codes.

Comment: i don't know the amount of columns it's gonna take (if the window is resized it is possible that they need more/less)

Comment: yes, but calculating the amount of rows/columns can't be the right way, as it would be very errorprone (by editing the Sticker size)

Comment: I don't know what are you saying without trying it and follow the links that I shared. I don't know what is the issue in this way. How it's not a right way. You don't need to edit the Sticker size?

Comment: i don't have the value you use for "rows"

Comment: Simply use box layout in that case. Take time and read more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Myself, I would try to keep things as simple as possible by putting images, ImageIcons actually, into a JList which can handle ImageIcons quite well. Give it a horizontal wrap set its visible row count to 0, plop it into a JScrollPane, and there you go.